# SharedGroupPreferences.getItem always return error 1 in Share Extension

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm working on react native app with share extension. For share extension, I'm using react-native-share-extension.
In share extension, I need to get the tokens which I stored in the Main app.

```
"react-native": "0.67.5",
"react-native-shared-group-preferences": "^1.1.23",
"react-native-share-extension": "2.0.0",
```

From Main App, I'm storing like

```
SharedGroupPreferences.setItem(
      'userDetail',
      JSON.stringify(userDetail),
      'group.com.projectName'
);
```

In Share Extension,

```
const userDetail = await SharedGroupPreferences.getItem(
      'userDetail',
      'group.com.projectName'
);
console.log(userDetail)
```

I have already added the 'group.com.projectName' in target -> App Groups.

Still I'm getting the 'error 1' when I'm trying to get the data in share extension But I'm getting the expected userDetail in Main app.

I'm expecting the user details in share extension as like main app receiving the user details.